CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: ''
When I run my app in the iOS Simulator I can see the following error messages in Xcode Console:

It happens when I navigate to a specific view. Looking online I found 2 reasons why this could happen:

UIImage(named:) is given an empty name, nil or '' (Error: CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: (null), or invalid scale factor : 2.000000)
If Selected Image is set in a Tab Bar in the storyboard:
Xcode 6 Beta 6 CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: (null), or invalid scale factor: 2.000000

I don't know what this error means. Does anybody know how to debug this?
Can I maybe use symbolic breakpoint to debug this?

After some debugging I eventually found the places in the code where UIImage(named:) was passed an empty string.
This issue is resolved now.
